# Should I already have a publication related to the NSF RUI proposal I will submit?

Tags: publications, funding, research-undergraduate, nsf

I am working on an NSF RUI proposal (research at an undergraduate institution). I have a manuscript on the subject that is languishing on the coauthors desk. How important is it that this manuscript be published before submitting my proposal? The manuscript is mentioned as prior work in the proposal but I fear that the proposal will be less effective without a publication directly related to it.

Answer (score 1):

A track record of relevant publications is very important to a successful grant application.  But the results you get in your case depends on the content of your application and the other applications submitted.